# CCNet WebDashboard get statisctic for count of Success/Failure builds

Tags: build-process, cruisecontrol.net

How can I modify the webdashboard of CCNet to display for the each of 10 servers:

How many builds successful?
How many builds failed ?

Is there any possibility to do so?

Comment: The only way I found is to create own plugin for CCNet with custom logic.http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/DevInfo_MakingPlugins

Answer (score 0):

The cruise control dashboard uses plugins which are written as `.xsl` files, it's not terribly well documented on the [wiki](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Configuring_the_Dashboard_().

You can create your reports by copying and modifying as required one of these .xsl files as required.

When you have a new .xsl file/s you'll need to add them to the `dashboard.config` for them to be visible via the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is to [create own plugin](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/DevInfo_MakingPlugins) for CCNet with custom logic.